# Dojo chart: zoom in values disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I am having an issue in Dojox charts wherein the zooming in operation is making the data points at the end of the series disappear for some reason. The more I zoom in the more data values I lose. Is there a workaround for this. I am using the MouseZoomAndPan module with a line chart.

Attaching code.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="atk.graph.*" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>        
    var c;
    <% String data = "[{value: 1, text: \"X\"}, {value: 2, text: \"Z\"}]"; %>  //  Some test labels

    <% String labels = new LabelMaker().makeLabels(10);%> // Generating labels in  java class   
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      @import
      url("http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css") ;
    </style>

    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.0/dojo/dojo.js'></script>

    <script>
    require(["dojox/charting/Chart", "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default", "dojox/charting/plot2d/StackedLines"
     , "dojo/ready", "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
     "dojox/charting/action2d/Highlight","dojox/charting/themes/PlotKit/blue","dojox/charting/action2d/MouseZoomAndPan"],
     function(Chart, _axis, StackedLines,ready, Tooltip,Highlight,theme_green, MouseZoomAndPan){
     ready(function(){
     c = new Chart("chartOne");
     c.setTheme(theme_green);
     c.addPlot("default", {type: StackedLines, markers: true, tension:3,  enable\Cache: true})
     .addAxis("x", {fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major", enableCache: true, majorTickStep:1, natural:false, fixed: true, minorTicks: false, labels: <% out.println(labels); %>})
     .addAxis("y", {vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major", min: 0, enableCache: true})
     .addSeries("Series A", [ 1, 2, 5, 0, 8,7, 20]);
     var anim2b = new Highlight(c, "default");       
     var animc = new Tooltip(c, "default"); 
     new MouseZoomAndPan(c, "default", {axis:"x"});
    c.render();     
     });
     });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
    <div id="chartOne"
    style="width: 800px; height: 540px; align:center";></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to be a version issue, fixed when switched to 1.10.1.